# Let $a,b$ nonnegative, $a\ge cb$ for every $c$ in $(0,1)$, Should $a \ge b$ be true?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

In the proof of monotone convergent theorem, The above technique is used. I really appreciate if anybody can explain it to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $a<b$. Then choose $c=\frac{b+a}{2b}$ and clearly we have $c<1$. Moreover:
$$
cb=\frac{b+a}2> \frac{a+a}2=a.
$$
which is not possible because for all $c\in(0,1)$ we have $cb\leq a$. Therefore $a\geq b$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $c\to 1^-$ then you get desired result.

---

More precisely, we assume that $b>0$. (The case of $b=0$ is trivial.) Let $c=1-\varepsilon/b$ for $0<\varepsilon<b$, then $a\ge b-\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon\in (0,b)$. You know that if $x\ge -\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ then $x\ge 0$, so $a\ge b$.